# Detect if label touches navigation bar

Tags: swift

I am trying to make view that is scrollable. That viewcontroller contains also navbar. Now my goal is to resize my view if the title in that view touches the navbar. How should I do it?

This is how my view looks like(note that the navBar is just transparent):

[image]

What I want after the title collision:

[image]

I know that I can achieve it in `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate function, but how?

Comment: *"Now my goal is to resize my view"* ... *"But this just resizes the view"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can track label position using convertRect: method as

```
 func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let labelTop = label.rectCorrespondingToWindow.minY
        let navBottom =  self.navigationController?.navigationBar.rectCorrespondingToWindow.maxY
        if navBottom == labelTop {
            // do what you want to do
        }
    }

extension UIView{
    var rectCorrespondingToWindow:CGRect{
        return self.convert(self.bounds, to: nil)
    }
}
```